# Problems serializing a list of nullable doubles using Protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net

I've been able to serialize nullable doubles without an issue, and can serialize Lists of nullable other types, but can't serialize Lists of nullable doubles.

If I do this:

```
        List<double?> aList = new List<double?>();
        aList.Add(0.1);
        aList.Add(null);
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, aList);
```

I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TrySerializeAuxiliaryType(ProtoWriter writer, Type type, DataFormat format, Int32 tag, Object value, Boolean isInsideList) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 169
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore(ProtoWriter writer, Object value) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 188
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value, SerializationContext context) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 217
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 201
>      at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 87

should this work? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I put a test together with a `List<int?>`, a `List<double?>` and a `List<string>` - they all behaved identically here

Comment: I'll rerun my test and return

Comment: I get the same behaviour will all nullable types. I think previously whilst I had nullable types, it was only the nullable double that had actual null values. Apologies for the misinformation. Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that the protobuf specification simply has no concept of null - explicitly null / missing values cannot be expressed in the protobuf format.

On a per-library basis, the library itself could choose to *spoof* an extra layer to allow for this kind of thing, but:

- it would take extra bytes on the wire
- it would complicate the code and require extra configuration
- it would (by necessity) disable optimisations like "packed" encoding

It should probably detect the null and behave better, though!

I would encourage you to serialize a list of things that *have* a nullable-value, rather than a list of null able values themselves. For example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo {
    [ProtoMember(1)] public double? Value {get;set;}
}
```

A list of the above *can* express null values. And is basically exactly the same as what I would write if I added inbuilt support for spoofing nulls.

Comment: it's strange to me that it works for other nullable types, but not doubles. Nevertheless your explanation makes sense, and I will use the suggested solution, thanks

Comment: @mcmillab wait... It worked with other nullables?? I will investigate, to double-check that there isn't something silly happening. What I said above remains true (format limitations etc) - but I'll see if there is something funky about double in particular